# Ajax working on pageload but not on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax query that's working if I call it from onpageload but not if I call it from a button click. Any reason why?

Edit: I've added the events as requested, please be aware I have debugged this and it is getting to the AJAX but just silently skipping it. It will call a failure function if I add one.

```
function detailsQuery(crn, semester, year, questionId, clickedButton)
{
    $.ajax({
                url: somebigurlwithnocallback (same domain),
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {alert(data)}});
}
```

-

```
   $(function() {
        $(document).delegate(".button", "click", function(){detailsQuery(CRN,Semester,Year,QuestionID, this);});

    });


window.onload=(function() {detailsQuery(CRN,Semester,Year,QuestionID, this);});
```

Comment: Can you show the event handlers for each?

Comment: ^What Patrick said. Oops :P

Comment: So why not just use .click?

Comment: What is "this" meant to refer to?

Comment: @jdero buttons can be added dynamically, using the document delegate I don't have to worry about adding it all the time.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts right now it does nothing, once I get it working it will be used to find the button who was clicked's siblings.

Comment: can you try `console.log` in the click callback function? if you don't see anything in the console, it would mean that your selector (the `.button`) is probably wrong.

Comment: It's definitely firing the detailsQuery function upon button click. If I debug it hits the '$.ajax({' line then just skips to the end of the detailsQuery function if I add a failure: the failure does get triggered.

Comment: any errors in the console? are the parameters (crn, semester, etc.) exactly the same as the one on load, or is it different?

Comment: They are global parameters so yeah. And no console output either. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Google Chrome. If  an HTML file is modified and only refreshed (even with ctrl+f5) Chrome does not always process the modified AJAX call properly. I don't have access to server side code so I can't see what's going on there, being a 'GET' not much can be going on. I can only see that it returns 'error'. Closing chrome and re-opening resolves the issue. Why it only happens when the AJAX occurs on a button click is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you attempt to check if the click event was even working ? Try this code:

```
   $(".button").live("click", function(){ 

   function detailsQuery(crn, semester, year, questionId, clickedButton)
   {

   $.ajax({
            url: somebigurlwithnocallback (same domain),
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",

    success: function (data) {alert(data)}
          });

              });
                    });
```

Comment: Yes it is working, like I said if I put in an error:function() on the ajax it will call it properly but with no data from the GET.

Answer (score 0):

Do this: 
Change

```
   $(function() {
        $(document).delegate(".button", "click", function(){detailsQuery(CRN,Semester,Year,QuestionID, this);});

    });
```

to

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").bind({"click": function(){
       function(){detailsQuery(CRN,Semester,Year,QuestionID, this);}
        } 
     });
});
```

That should resolve the issue. 
 
Hope the explanation is clear and this helps.

Comment: Is this intended to fix the delegate binding? Because the binding is actually working fine.

Comment: Well, the stated that the function wasn't working when the button is clicked; this is simply another way to achieve the same result.