# issue with ajax working on page load but not on button click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been playing around with ajax for awhile, to get some info out of a database. I finally got it to work in my testfile, so I copied the code to my real file. It worked. And then it didn't. To be specific, when I use my code when the document finishes loading, it works fina and as expected, but when I click on a button, it does not. The ajax.php file isn't the issue, it works both in the document load and when I call it directly from my browser. So what's the issue here?

Working code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="testsi2.php">
<p><button id="submitOV">submit this</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("page loaded");
    var selectedVak = 7;
    var selectedKlas = 2;
    var selectedJaar = 2023;
    console.log("prepping ajax call");
    var url = "ajax.php?vak=" + selectedVak + "&klas=" + selectedKlas + "&jaar=" + selectedJaar + "&task=4";
    console.log("calling " + url);
    $.ajax(url, { success: function(data) { 
                console.log("AJAX call was successful.");
                console.log("Data from the server = " + data);
            },
            error: function() { console.log("There was some error performing the AJAX call."); } }
    );
});

</script>
```

This echoes in the console, as expected:

```
page loaded
prepping ajax call
calling ajax.php?vak=7&klas=2&jaar=2023&task=4
AJAX call was successful.
Data from the server = 6-3-5-4-3-
```

The 6-3-5-4-3- is exactly the response I want, so that's all fine.

And this does not:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="testsi2.php">
<p><button id="submitOV">submit this</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#submitOV").click(function(event) {
    console.log("button clicked");
    var selectedVak = 7;
    var selectedKlas = 2;
    var selectedJaar = 2023;
    console.log("prepping ajax call");
    var url = "ajax.php?vak=" + selectedVak + "&klas=" + selectedKlas + "&jaar=" + selectedJaar + "&task=4";
    console.log("calling " + url);
    $.ajax(url, { success: function(data) { 
                console.log("AJAX call was successful.");
                console.log("Data from the server = " + data);
            },
            error: function() { console.log("There was some error performing the AJAX call."); } }
    );
});
```

As you can see, the only thing changed is calling the ajax when I click the button instead of loading the page, and the first console.log() entry.

This time, I get

```
button clicked 
prepping ajax call 
calling ajax.php?vak=7&klas=2&jaar=2023&task=4
There was some error performing the AJAX call.
```

I have found this one:  [Ajax working on pageload but not on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713042/ajax-working-on-pageload-but-not-on-button-click)  but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Find exact error via:  `error: function(xhr, status, error) {console.log(xhr.responseText);}` , it's help to dive dipper :)

Comment: This just echoes `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

The `action` attribute tells the form which page to post the data to when the form is submitted. There's no code preventing this from happening, so even though your request likely goes through as expected, the browser is also navigating to this page, because that's what it's been told to do.

You should listen to the `submit` event of the form itself, rather than the click event of the button. This will have a couple benefits: it will let you use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the page redirect as long as JavaScript is enabled, and it will also make it so other methods of form submission (enter key, etc.) are also intercepted.

It would look something like this:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="testsi2.php">
    <p><button type="submit">submit this</button>
</form>

...

<script>
$("#form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the page redirect
    // your submit handler here
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because clicking the button sends a request to `testsi2.php` and reloads the page, and your AJAX request gets aborted. If you move the button out of the form, it works fine.

Comment: This works, yes, but gives me another issue - I can't submit my form anymore. For that, the button needs to be inside the form.

Comment: Then you can manually submit the form from JavaScript after the AJAX request is done.

Comment: I found a work around. I'm doing the ajax call when in my form the field that yields selectedVak is selected, store that in a variable, and then use the variable when I'm clicking the button.

Comment: You can submit a form with a button outside of the form element by giving it a `form="form_id"` attribute @Patrick